# How mount a svfs file system with user permissions? (without sudo)

Tags: linux, mount, fuse

In the context of an application that transfers some files to an ovh storage, and I am experiencing some problems mounting a fuse file system.

This is the structure of my mount point in fstab

```
mystorage   /mnt/openstack  svfs    username=my-user-name,password=my-password,tenant=my-tenant,region=BHS1,container=my-container-name,noauto,users,user,suid,rw 1
```

According to my understanding, this line would allow executing

```
mount /mnt/openstack
```

to any user. In effect, I successfully mount the fuse file system. Unfortunately, and this is my specific problem, after mounting I cannot neither copy nor read what is inside the `/mnt/openstack` directory because I do not have permissions. However, I am sure the file system is mounted because through `sudo` I can manipulate the directory without any problem. For instance, the commands:

```
sudo ls -l /mnt/openstack
```

which oputputs:

```
total 0
-rwx------ 1 root root 432249 May  2 09:02 26-14818.jpg
-rwx------ 1 root root    447 Apr 29 11:14 401error.html
-rwx------ 1 root root    438 Apr 29 11:14 404error.html
-rwx------ 1 root root    468 Apr 29 11:14 503error.html
drwx------ 1 root root   4096 Aug 30  1754 images
-rwx------ 1 root root    313 Apr 29 11:14 index.html
-rwx------ 1 root root   1876 Apr 29 11:14 listing.css
drwx------ 1 root root   4096 Aug 30  1754 styles
```

and

```
sudo cp a-file /mnt/openstack
```

work perfectly.

EDITED:

The output of `sudo ls -ld /mnt/openstack`

```
drwx------ 1 root root 665505 May  3 08:53 /mnt/openstack
```

A remark: the permissions of `/mnt/openstack` before mounting are 777`

So my questions are: what am I doing wrong? What could I do in order to manage mounting and manipulate the mounted directory as the user?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `sudo ls -ld /mnt/openstack` and `sudo ls -l /mnt/openstack` (edit your question to include the output)

Comment: @EightBitTony I edited the question and put the output that you request. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `mount` does not support this use of `user` with the default fuse security setting (or `allow_root`).  I think the resulting permissions are the same as if you used `sudo mount`.  To allow access by multiple non-root users, you could set `allow_other`, allowing access by *any* user.

If this raised concerns, it would be possible to set `default_permissions` to enable permissions checking, set a group with the `gid=` mount option, add selected users to that group, and set `mode=770` to allow full read-write access by the group.

Or if you only need access by your user, you could simply use `allow_other,default_permissions,uid=user`.  Note that in this case there's no particular need to use `fstab`.  You could save your mount command as a script instead, call it something like `mount-openstack` and put it `~/.local/bin`.

Comment: I solved thus: `noauto,user,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=user`. Apparently, it works! Thanks!